# Saving uploaded file as a dataframe on RMD in Shiny runtime mode

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, r-markdown

I am enjoying unlimited possibilities of RMD in statistics and data analysis. I have learnt to conduct such analysis using RMarkdown using knitr through RStudio. Now I want users to upload their files through a browser and pass on the read data to a dataframe for further analysis. I could do this when I have ui.R and server.R seperately. But unfortunately, I could not pass it on to a dataframe variable in  Shiny runtime mode using RMD. I need this dataframe to be processed and to display some static plots which are in the RMD as separate chunks. In between these chunks, I have headings, texts.

The code I used is given below:

````
---
title: "shinyRMD"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(shiny)
inputPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose a file to upload',
            accept = c(
              'text/csv',
              'text/comma-separated-values',
              'text/tab-separated-values',
              'text/plain',
              '.csv',
              '.tsv'
            )
    )
)
renderDataTable({    
    if(is.null(input$file1))return()
    inFile <- input$file1
    data2<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    assign('dataread',data2,envir=.GlobalEnv)
    save(dataread, file = "dataread.RData")
})

#df<-dataread
#df<-data2
```
````

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't assign to the user's global environment from a `shiny session`, but `save` does work:

```
rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

observe( {
  req(input$file1)

  inFile <- input$file1
  data2 <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  save(data2, file = "dataread.RData")

  rv$data <- data2
})

DT::renderDataTable({
  req(rv$data)
  rv$data
})
```

This functionality is more suited to [Shiny gadgets](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/gadgets.html) though. (Run app, do something, get a return value)

You can define a function called `myGadgetFunc`. Then by running `my_data <- myGadgetFunc()` in RStudio, the user can upload a file, see it's contents in the `tableOutput` and when clicking `done`, the `returnValue` is then assigned to `my_data` in the `global environment`.

```
library(shiny)
library(miniUI)

myGadgetFunc <- function() {

  ui <- miniPage(
    gadgetTitleBar("My Gadget"),
    miniContentPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose a file to upload',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  'text/tab-separated-values',
                  'text/plain',
                  '.csv',
                  '.tsv'
                )
      )
    ),
    DT::dataTableOutput("tbl")


  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

    observe( {
      req(input$file1)

      inFile <- input$file1
      data2 <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      save(data2, file = "dataread.RData")

      rv$data <- data2
    })

    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable({
      req(rv$data)
      rv$data
    })

    # When the Done button is clicked, return a value
    observeEvent(input$done, {
      returnValue <- rv$data
      stopApp(returnValue)
    })
  }

  runGadget(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: Please note I am running the RMD in runtime shiny mode, when I run this code I get an error, "Can't call runAppI() from within 'runApp()'....am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I didn't make it clear, but these are 2 separate solutions: 1. in your `RMD` file you should replace the `renderDataTable` with the first snippet (`observe`). This way you can't assign to your global environment, but you can `save` the file, and afterwards `load` it.

Comment: The second (`ShinyGadget`) is a completely separate solution for this problem. It allows you to run a `Shiny` app and get a `returnValue` that you can work with later on.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When I tried your first solution, i get this error: object 'rv' not found

Comment: You're right, sorry! I forgot to copy `rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)` into my solution... Now it should be fine.

Comment: Its ok, i used the above and get no error. But could you please help me how to call this dataframe in another chunk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165490/discussion-between-gyd-and-doctshind-s).